# GRPC test client GUI that supports representing a bytes type as a hex string?

Tags: mongodb, protocol-buffers, grpc

MongoDB's ObjectID type is a 12 byte array. When you view the database, you can see it displayed as: ObjectId("6000e9720C683f1b8e638a49").

We also want to share this value with SQL server and pass it into a GRPC request.
When the same value stored in MS SQL server as a binary(12) column, it is displayed as: 0x6000E9720C683F1B8E638A49. It's simple enough to convert this representation to the Mongo representation.

However, when trying to pass it via GRPC as a bytes type, BloomRPC requires that we represent it in the format: "id": [96,0,233,114,12,104,63,27,142,99,138,73]

So I'm looking for a GRPC test client GUI application to replace BloomRPC that will support a hex string format similar to MongoDB or SQL server to represent the underlying byte array. Anyone have a line on something like this that could work?

We could just represent it as a string in the proto, but my personal opinion is that it should be unnecessary to do this. It will require our connected services to convert bytes->string->bytes on every GRPC call. The other 2 tools seem to be happy having a byte array in the background and representing it as a string in the front end, so if we could just get our last tool to behave the same, that would be great.

Comment: Do you already have seen this list? https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/awesome-grpc#gui

Comment: Yep, I tested a bunch of the tools on that list and none of them seemed to support what we are looking for.